# Unusual "static" method declaration

Tags: java

```
public class Card {

    public enum Rank { DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
        SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE }

    public enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES }

    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;
    private Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Rank rank() { return rank; }
    public Suit suit() { return suit; }
    public String toString() { return rank + " of " + suit; }

    private static final List<Card> protoDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    // Initialize prototype deck
    **static** {
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values())
            for (Rank rank : Rank.values())
                protoDeck.add(new Card(rank, suit));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Card> newDeck() {
        return new ArrayList<Card>(protoDeck); // Return copy of prototype deck
    }
}
```

I have a quick question. The code block that starts right after the static keyword declaration, what type of method is that ? I haven't ever seen that before. If anyone could enlighten me, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not a method, but a static Initializer block of a class. You can read more about it in the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#39245).

The code within is executed once after loading the class.

Comment: +1: Concise, with reference for further reading, and clear explanation. This is what SO is all about...

Answer (score 3):

As Grzegorz correctly points out, it's a **[static initializer block](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#39245)**.

[Here is another resource](http://norvig.com/java-iaq.html#init2) explaining the difference between **class initialization** and **instantiation**, as well as the order in which class variables and static initializer blocks are called.

A related concept is that of **instance initializer blocks**, which can be used together with anonymous classes for the handy **[double-brace initialization](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization)** idiom:

```
private static final Set<String> VALID_CODES = new HashSet<String>() {{
    add("XZ13s");
    add("AB21/X");
    add("YYLEX");
    add("AR2D");
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also good to know initialization order, as I remember first in this order comes static variables, than static block. Also important point is time when this static block executes - at the first mention of corresponding class, not at the class instance creation.