# Java: Strange static method head definition (expression instead of return type)

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static Initialization Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks)
>   [Unusual “static” method declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902833/unusual-static-method-declaration)

I'm trying to prepare for a OCJPC in the near future, and I came across a construct I had never seen before. As it is tough to google for programming constructs, I am asking the question here. The code fragment:

```
class Geryon {
    static { System.out.print("a"); }
    { System.out.print("b"); }
    Geryon(String s) { System.out.print(s); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Geryon("c");
    }
}
```

I am referring to the 2 print statements inside `theGeryon()` method header in the place where I would expect a return type. As far as I was able to google, a static method header consists of:

```
access-modifier keyword-"static" return-type|void method-name
```

Judging from the answer to the quiz question, the code does not only compile, but will also be run. Can anyone direct me to a source where this is explained?

Comment: @AVD : Question does not have non-static block `{...}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A is a static initializer that gets called when the class is initialized by classloader, this :

```
 static { System.out.print("a"); }
```

And the other (B) is an anonymous block that gets called every time the class is instantiated :

```
{ System.out.print("b"); }
```

Oh and the third print statement, C, is just a normal constructor call.

You will get all three lines if you instantiated one Geryon, like the code you posted. But then the next time you instantiated a Geryon you will only get two - B and C; as it has already been initialized by classloader, so the static block does not get called.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the answer. I am currently looking through the Java Language Specification, it has to be in there somewhere.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE - try searching the Table of Contents or the index ... or the PDF version.